# Is smoking herbs halal?

Tags: halal-haram, sunni, smoking

Is it halal to smoke herbs? It does not contain any tobacco or marijuana. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1):

May Peace be upon you, If you smoke herbs ,even if you justify it to be a non harmful substance, it will be still considered a wastage of money which could have been put to good use. You can have a look at what our scholars have to say here: https://islamqa.info/en/answers/10922/the-reason-why-smoking-is-haraam

Moreover we humans haven't done enough research to conclude that smoking herbs is okay for our body.

I would advice you to attain the path of Takwa (abstain from doubtful venture for the sake of Allah ).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Jazakallah khairan.   I'm interested to ask this question because it's not the same as cannabis or tobacco and the herbs has medicinal benefit to it, I guess if not smoke it I can always put it in tea or something lol.

Comment: Please clarify, wastage of money is it haram or not? Also would you consider drinking soda that rather has no benefits, to be wastage of money? Buying an expensive car, etc... Is lack of research a reason to conclude something is bad/haram? Is everything that is harmful (or a bit harmful) considered haram? If that is the case, what are the sources of that?